# Is there a phrase to describe this kind of link, such as "a link with time point"?

Tags: meaning

I linked a youtube video at precise time https://youtu.be/3P49hWpNIzA?t=62 in this [post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/183812/111759), which means clicking the link in that post could open a youtube page and play the video from a precise time (1:02 in this case).

Is there a phrase to describe this kind of link, such as "a link with time point"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen many times people on YouTube write *time stamps* for the time marks. I believe this would be "a link with a **time stamp**".